# configuring QT with webassembly issue: failed on Qt6ProtobufTools, WrapProtoc not found

Tags: qt, cmake, webassembly

This is what I did and tried,
I installed QT 6.5.2, I also downloaded emsdk
I install and activate emsdk by

```
./emsdk install 3.1.25
./emsdk activate 3.1.25
```

and i went to the QT source folder at C:\Qt\6.5.2\Src
and run configuration

```
./configure.bat -qt-host-path C:\Qt\6.5.2\mingw_64 -no-warnings-are-errors -feature-opengles3  -device-option QT_EMSCRIPTEN_ASYNCIFY=1 -platform wasm-emscripten -prefix $PWD/qtbase
```

and I got the following errors

```
-- Configuring submodule 'qtwebengine'
[QtWebEngine] -- Support check for QtWebEngine failed: Build can be done only on Linux, Windows or macOS.
[QtWebEngine] -- Support check for QtPdf failed: Build can be done only on Linux, Windows, macO, iOS and Android(on non-Windows hosts only).
-- Configuring submodule 'qtdoc'
-- Configuring submodule 'qtgrpc'
CMake Warning at qtgrpc/src/tools/host/CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6ProtobufTools/Qt6ProtobufToolsConfig.cmake

  but it set Qt6ProtobufTools_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6ProtobufTools" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Qt6ProtobufTools could not be found because dependency WrapProtoc could not
  be found.



CMake Warning at qtgrpc/src/tools/host/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6GrpcTools/Qt6GrpcToolsConfig.cmake

  but it set Qt6GrpcTools_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6GrpcTools" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Qt6GrpcTools could not be found because dependency WrapProtoc could not be
  found.



CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtPublicTargetHelpers.cmake:257 (get_property):
  get_property could not find TARGET Qt6::qtprotobufgen.  Perhaps it has not
  yet been created.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6ProtobufTools/Qt6ProtobufToolsConfig.cmake:56 (__qt_internal_promote_target_to_global)
  qtbase/cmake/QtToolHelpers.cmake:642 (find_package)
  qtbase/cmake/QtToolHelpers.cmake:72 (qt_internal_find_tool)
  qtgrpc/src/tools/qtprotobufgen/CMakeLists.txt:5 (qt_internal_add_tool)


CMake Warning at qtbase/cmake/QtToolHelpers.cmake:642 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/Qt/6.5.2/mingw_64/lib/cmake/Qt6ProtobufTools/Qt6ProtobufToolsConfig.cmake

  but it set Qt6ProtobufTools_FOUND to FALSE so package "Qt6ProtobufTools" is
  considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by package:

  Qt6ProtobufTools could not be found because dependency WrapProtoc could not
  be found.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtToolHelpers.cmake:72 (qt_internal_find_tool)
  qtgrpc/src/tools/qtprotobufgen/CMakeLists.txt:5 (qt_internal_add_tool)


CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtToolHelpers.cmake:684 (message):
  Failed to find the host tool "Qt6::qtprotobufgen".  It is part of the
  Qt6ProtobufTools package, but the package could not be found.  Make sure
  you have built and installed the host Protobuf module, which will ensure
  the creation of the Qt6ProtobufTools package.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtToolHelpers.cmake:72 (qt_internal_find_tool)
  qtgrpc/src/tools/qtprotobufgen/CMakeLists.txt:5 (qt_internal_add_tool)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Qt/6.5.2/Src/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Qt/6.5.2/Src/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtProcessConfigureArgs.cmake:998 (message):
  CMake exited with code 1.
```

I have checked my QT installation and confirmed that everything needed for QT was installed
[image]

googling the errors yields no good result.
What am I missing and needed to do here?

Answer (score 0):

`apt install protobuf-compiler` resolved a similar issue for me.